# Visual Basic Memory Management Form.Show

Tags: vba

I have a question on memory management within Visual Studio using Visual Basic.

I have a form with a button. When the button is pressed a second form that I have created appears. I am using the code below to show the second form:

```
Form2.show()
```

My question is: When I press the button in the first form , is the second form loaded into memory, or has it been loaded from the start of the program, but just hidden?

Is there a way to unload the form after it has been loaded, so that it doesn't take up memory anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Unload Form2` to unload the form from memory. The `show` method simply shows the already memory loaded form.

`Load Form2` is used to load the form into memory. But `Form2.Show`is only used to show it for the user.

Comment: Thank you, so in other words, when I run my application with the two forms, the second form is loaded and hidden?

Would it not be better to load the form as I press the button? If you know how I can do this, I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: It's automatically loaded if you haven't done it manually. But it stays in memory unless you use `Unload Form2`

Comment: @EliasWick The form does get loaded when you press the button.  According to MSDN "If the specified form isn't loaded when the Show method is invoked, Visual Basic automatically loads it."